# Distribute menu tab evenly in CSS3

Tags: iphone, html, css

How to distribute menu tab evenly in CSS3. There is three tabs and one tab with obvious wider gap between tab two and three, than  tab one and two?

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/tabs_uneven.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/tabs_uneven.png)

```
  ul.tabsmenu{ padding:5px 0 0 0; position:relative; bottom:-1px;}
  ul.tabsmenu li a{ width:31.2%; float:left; padding:12px 0 12px 0; margin:0 2% 0 0;color:#000000;text-align:center; 
  -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;-khtml-border-top-left-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;-khtml-border-top-right-radius:5px;
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffffff 100%);background: 
  -webkit gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#ececec), to(#ffffff)); }
  ul.tabsmenu li:last-child a{ float:right; margin:0 0 0 0;}
  ul.tabsmenu li.active a{border-bottom-color:#fff; color:#48c4d2; 
  font-weight:bold; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e4f6f8 0%, #ffffff 100%);background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#e4f6f8), to(#ffffff)); }
  .tabcontent{ padding:5% 4%; clear:both; border:1px #bfeaf0 solid; margin:0 0 15px 0; /* ddd darker grey. border:1px #bfeaf0 solid; */
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;-khtml-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;-khtml-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
```

}

Comment: @IlanBiala - Konqueror and any other browser that uses the KHTML layout engine (which is where Webkit originates from).

Comment: i don't think anyone uses khtml....never seen it in most developers code like Chris Coyier and Lea Verou.

Answer (score 3):

Using `inline-block` for the list items and set a left margin on all but the first one. The left margin will have a value of `(100% - 3*31.2%)/2 = (100% - 93.6%)/2 = 6.4%/2 = 3.2%`

## [demo](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/gwJEj)

```
<ul class='tabsmenu'>
  <li><a href='#'>Tab one</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Tab two</a></li>
  <li class='active'><a href='#'>Tab three</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class='tabcontent'>
  <li><!-- content--></li>
  <li><!-- content--></li>
  <li><!-- content--></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
.tabsmenu{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.tabsmenu li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31.2%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#ececec, #fff);
}
.tabsmenu li:not(:first-child) { margin-left: 3.2%; }
.tabsmenu li.active {
  border: solid 1px #bfeaf0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(#e4f6f8, #fff);
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tabsmenu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 0 12px 0;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabsmenu li.active a { color:#48c4d2; }
.tabcontent{
  padding: 5% 4%;
  border: solid 1px #bfeaf0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
```

---

Or floating the list items. Not much changes:

```
.tabsmenu{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.tabsmenu li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 31.2%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#ececec, #fff);
}
```

---

Or using absolute positioning. Since you have the widths for each, then you can easily absolutely position them. Have the first at the `left` (`left: 0`), the third at the `right`, and the second one at `50% - (31.2% / 2) = 50% - 15.6% = 34.%` from either `left` or `right` (`left: 34.4%`).

## [demo](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/LAyCi)

**CSS** changes wrt the first method:

```
.tabsmenu{
  position: relative;
  height: 28px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.tabsmenu li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 31.2%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#ececec, #fff);
}
.tabsmenu li:first-child { left: 0; }
.tabsmenu li:nth-child(2) { left: 34.4%; }
.tabsmenu li:last-child { right: 0; }
```

Comment: @joshnh: Ok, how can you suggest to evenly distribute the tabs menu? In code please?

Comment: Like this http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/gwJEj with `inline-block`, which I agree is the better solution. I simply went for absolute positioning because I saw `position: relative` on their parent.

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your CSS:

```
    ul.tabsmenu li:last-child a{ float:right; margin:0 0 0 0;}
```

If your container is wider than the 3 tabs with the margins then it will show a larger gap on this one only.
Do not float this to the right - instead keep them all left and either work out the box model size of these and do the Math or use box-sizing:border-box and 33% widths for the tabs. NB be careful though as margins are not included in box-sizing only borders and paddings so reduce down to say 30% to be safe.